# storing sqlite database online

Tags: android, iphone, database, sqlite

Previously, I developed an application with an internal sqlite database stored. 
Now I need to upload that database in an online server so that admins can easily modify the contents.

Is it possible for my app to access/use the sqlite database online?

The application is done on both ios and android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS it is not possible to access an online database. You should send the data to a server side script like php and from there parse it into your database. Only need to recreate your database format on the server end.

Or export the database as a file and import it on your server with something like phpMyAdmin or something. It can import all different kinds of formats like .sql, .csv, .txt.. Whatever you like.

Good luck!

Hmm, after rereading I think you ask the question if the app is able to use the database from an online source after importing it there? Am I correct?

Simple answer.. for iOS. No. You have to return results to the app by using a POST or GET request.

Comment: How would I go about doing this if I were to use a web server like XAMPP? Thanks.